# Use Javascript to cycle through video backgrounds and change CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like to use a div (#button) to cycle through four different states and change specific CSS properties on click; it would make sense to use Javascript or jQuery.

The default state is a white background with the specific CSS properties listed below as-is. The next 3 states use an HTML5 video for the background and the CSS properties all need to switch to #fff. So the page starts at default and when the button div is clicked it will be: vid1, vid2, vid3, return to default, vid1, vid2, vid3, default...etc. with the CSS set to #000 for default and #fff for the videos.

The HTML for the video background; the source link to both the mp4 and webm version will need to be updated with vid2, vid3, etc.

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="bgvid">
    <source src="videos/vid1.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="videos/vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The follow CSS properties are what I'd like to change, when in the 3 states with a video background.

```
h1 {color: #000;}
p {color: #000;}
h1 a {color: #000;}
#button:active {background-color: #000;}
#nav-icon span {background: #000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with creating some nice array, containing CSS classes and list of video sources for each step.

Next, I'd create `video` tags as needed, based on the data in Array. You could create video tags for each step at the beginning, showing and hiding appropriate ones for each step.

You could also create one `video` tag and deleting previous one, after clicking the button.

For each step you can have a CSS class, which you'll apply to some parent element (such like `body`) after clicking a button. That way you can neatly separate styles from actual JavaScript.

## Proof of concept

```js
$(function(){
  var steps = [
    {
      cssClass: 'default'
    },
    {
      cssClass: 'video',
      sources: [
        ['videos/vid1.webm', 'video/webm'],
        ['videos/vid1.mp4', 'video/mp4']
      ]
    },
    {
      cssClass: 'step3',
      sources: [
        ['videos/vid2.webm', 'video/webm'],
        ['videos/vid2.mp4', 'video/mp4']
      ]
    }
  ];
  
  $('button').click(function(){
    if (steps.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    
    var prevStepIndex = parseInt($(this).data('step') || 0);
    var currentStepIndex = prevStepIndex + 1;
    if (currentStepIndex >= steps.length) {
      currentStepIndex = 0;
    }
    var currentStep = steps[currentStepIndex];
    
    $('body').attr('class', currentStep.cssClass || '');
    
    $(this).data({'step': currentStepIndex});
    $('#step').text(currentStepIndex);
  });
});
```

```css
.default h1,
.default h1 a,
.default p {
  color: #000;
}

.default #button:active,
.default #nav-icon span {
  background: #000;
}

.video h1,
.video h1 a,
.video p {
  color: #fff;
}

.video #button:active,
.video #nav-icon span {
  background: #fff;
}

.step3 h1,
.step3 h1 a,
.step3 p {
  color: red;
}

.step3 #button:active,
.step3 #nav-icon span {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Test header</h1>
<button>Change!</button>
Current step: <span id="step"/>
```